# get html output from mathquill in javascript function

Tags: javascript, latex

I would like to use mathquill to get html ouput in a string var, in a javascript code.

Something like

```
var latexCode = 'x^2';
var htmlText = mathquill(....
```

Thanks,

Mathieu

Comment: Could you explain more what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need rendered latex in Javascript? I think you should try this.

```
$('<span>x^2</span>').appendTo('body').mathquill() or .mathquill('editable')
```

Or if you want any comparison

```
$('<span>x^{-1}</span>').mathquill().mathquill('latex') === 'x^{-1}'
```